# MYSQL Query does not return results with BETWEEN but it returns results with less than and equals to in subquery

Tags: mysql, between

For some strange reason if I use BETWEEN in my query it does not return any results.  (FYI I simplified this query for easier debugging but even in this easier state I am seeing the issue)

This query does not return results:

```
SELECT 
u.agent_number,
u.reporting_week
FROM table1 e
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   b.agent_number,
   b.reporting_week
   FROM table2 b
   GROUP BY b.agent_number
) u ON u.agent_number = e.agent_number
WHERE u.reporting_week BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-07 00:00:00';
```

But this query does return results with `>` and `<`:

```
SELECT 
u.agent_number,
u.reporting_week
FROM table1 e
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   b.agent_number,
   b.reporting_week
   FROM table2 b
   GROUP BY b.agent_number
) u ON u.agent_number = e.agent_number
WHERE u.reporting_week > '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND  u.reporting_week < '2019-01-07 00:00:00';
```

I have a record with a date of `2019-01-02 10:00:00`.

FYI the below does give a result. It only has issues if in the JOIN:

```
SELECT 
b.agent_number,
b.reporting_week
FROM table2 b
WHERE b.reporting_week BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-23 00:00:00';
```

**Edit**

Another weird thing I found is if I run the query with the BETWEEN on my liver mysql database it gives a result. If I run it locally it does not.  So Weird.  Is there some kind of mysql setting that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT data_date from
(select '2019-01-02 10:00:00' data_date union ALL
select '2019-01-28 10:00:00') d
where DATE_FORMAT(date(data_date),'%Y-%m-%d %r') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %r') AND DATE_FORMAT(date('2019-01-07 00:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %r');
```

or

```
SELECT 
u.agent_number,
u.reporting_week
FROM table1 e
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   b.agent_number,
   b.reporting_week
   FROM table2 b
   GROUP BY b.agent_number
) u ON u.agent_number = e.agent_number

where DATE_FORMAT(date(u.reporting_week),'%Y-%m-%d %r') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %r') AND DATE_FORMAT(date('2019-01-07 00:00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %r');
```

Comment: That actually works but I can't explain why it doesn't work my way.